# UIScrollview not recognizing swipe from screen edge

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a `UIView` containing a `UIScrollview`. I have set the `UIView` as the header view of my `UITableView`. Now my `UITableView` is 20px narrower than the screen itself but I have seit its header view to fit the screen size.

The problem I am having now is that I cant swipe the `UIScrollview` coming in from the screens edge on both sides. It will only start paging when I touch inside of the screen.

Is there a way to fix this? 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just fix it by

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

Put this line in `viewDidLoad` method and then create other controllers.

It's only working on iOS 7 and latter.